# IIS 10 - All pool crash when changing a binding on a site

Tags: .net, iis

Sometimes on my IIS some application pools crash.
At first it seemed a random issue, but observing correlation with actions on the server, now I can say that this is related to changes in binding in one of the sites of the server.

On this **IIS 10** server I have deployed:

- 16 .Net 6 WebAPI sites
- 4 web UIs

The last time I changed a binding on one of the UIs, 7 of the APIs crashed all with the same reason (seen from Event Viewer):

- Source: IIS-W3SVC-WP
- Level: Error
- Detail:

> The worker process for application pool 'xxxxx' encountered an error
> 'Cannot read configuration file ' trying to read configuration data
> from file '\?\C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\xxxxx\xxxxx.config', line
> number '0'.  The data field contains the error code.

Is anyone else experiencing the same thing?

Comment: Since IIS isn't open sourced and this part is not very well documented, you should contact Microsoft support to get assistance. Such happened a lot, especially on busy machines, and was discussed in many posts like https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/http-503-with-trying-to-read-configuration-data-from-file-error/ba-p/308515

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because of the problems happened while creating the virtual directory and application pool. Missing config files that might have been removed somehow could be another possible cause .

A few things to try to solve this issue:

1. Remove everything in the temp application pool directory (C:\inetpub\temp\apppools). This will require restarting the machine
2. Check antivirus software’s logs. It may be removing the config files in the temp\apppools folder. Define an exception for this folder if needed.
3. Check if IIS_IUSRS has Read access on application folders which are referenced by virtual folders
4. Make sure IIS_IUSRS has access for C:\inetpub\temp folder
5. Make sure that you have enough free disk space in the server
6. Execute chkdsk in Command Prompt and make sure fix the issues found
7. Remove and recreate the application pool
8. Remove and recreate the virtual folder